# Interpreting substantial effects with a standardised dependent variable

Tags: least-squares, standardization

I would like to know what constitutes a substantial change in my dependent variable.

My dependent variable has been standardised in the data set. It has a range of -3 to +1 and is a measure of a nations political stability. I know that the coefficient of my IV represents the SD change in the DV for a one unit increase in the IV.

However, I am struggling to determine if the changes are substantial. What information must I consider to appreciate whether or not, say a coefficient of 0.46, is substantial?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a statistical question, it is a substantive one. You need to look at a change in the IV predicts about the DV and then judge, based on your substantive expertise, whether it is substantial or not.

Comment: OK thank you. Sorry if my question has broken the rules.

Comment: @PetterFlom Your answer seems to be a good comment so shouldn't it be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @MichaelChernick  No, I don't think so.  It answers the question and, if I make it a comment, then it doesn't look like an answer.  Although perhaps the question should be deleted as off-topic, I am not sure.